# GORM reference table for MemSQL

Tags: grails, grails-orm, singlestore

I want to create a reference table in my MemSQL database using a GORM domain object. This will allow our Grails server to create/drop reference tables in MemSQL for development.

Is it possible using GORM to add a reference table to a domain object other than specifying the primary key on the table?

---

Example:

```
create reference table calendar (
    dt DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    y SMALLINT NULL,
    q tinyint NULL,
    m tinyint NULL,
    d tinyint NULL,
    dw tinyint NULL,
    monthName VARCHAR(9) NULL,
    dayName VARCHAR(9) NULL,
    w tinyint NULL,
    isWeekday BINARY(1) NULL,
    isHoliday BINARY(1) NULL,
    holidayDescr VARCHAR(32) NULL,
    isPayday BINARY(1) NULL
);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, not through GORM. It doesn't know anything about MemSQL reference tables. Nor does it provide a way to create tables. Instead it creates tables for you based on your domain models through Hibernate. In particular, through a Hibernate dialect.

What you can do is create a Hibernate [dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html) for memSQL which generates the SQL you need. For example, by implementing `getCreateTableString()`. You can begin by extending the dialect for MySQL, that way you won't have to code the whole thing from scratch.

Then, you need to tell Grails to use your dialect in the datasource configuration.